# VS Code : brackets and parenthesis remain yellow - doesn't matter what theme I select

Tags: visual-studio-code, themes

Screenshot of the default Dark theme:

[image: Picture of the default Dark theme]

Atom one light theme:

[image: atom one light theme]

When I change the theme, the brackets and parenthesis remain the same color. I tried disabling Bracket Pair Colorization, but the yellow brackets remained. It does not matter what theme I select they stay yellow.

This is how the Atom one light theme should look according to its docs:

[image]

Comment: you can customize the color for the brackets per theme, until the theme maintainer sets some colors

Answer (score 9):

This is a relatively new feature included in VSCode that colorizes bracket pairs by default.

If you want to revert to **not colorizing** brackets, add the following in your `settings.json` file:

```
"editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": false
```

Comment: He says he tried that in the question.

Comment: he says he tried it, but it works for me (and I assume for many others)